# vb accessing nested components within component

Tags: vb.net, components

vb home made components and accessing nesting components within via the form they are added to.
I have created a component that includes several buttons, etc...When I add this component to a form, I only have access to the properties of that component and not the "nested" buttons in the component. At runtime, when in debug mode, I can click on one of the buttons within the "parent" component and gain access to the code for the button. However, I need to gain access to the button via the form the "parent" component is put on. There are multiples of this component added to the form in question and I need to get data of which one was selected and the like.
Any help would be great

Comment: Are you talking about User Controls?  Components *per se* dont usually have a visual element

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly access child controls in a compound     UserControl. To do that you have to define properties and methods in your     UserControl, perhaps if you provide us with some of your code and tell us what exactly you want to do then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Select the control you want to access in the UserControl designer. In the Properties window in the "Design" section change the `Modifiers` property from `Private` to either `Public` or `Internal`.

Now the control is accessible from outside the UserControl. This works for controls on forms as well.

You can also directly change the access modifier in the code of `theUserControl.designer.cs` where the control is declared. Before doing this it is advisable to close the designer, if it should be open.

---

Maybe a cleaner approach is to encapsulate the control in a property

```
public TextBox MyTextBox { get { return textBox1; } }
```

If you only need to access a specific property of it, then an even cleaner approach is to encapsulate this very property

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

then the code accessing this property is not dependent on a specific control.